# Objectify - @Embedded Error saving XXX is not a supported property type

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

When trying to save an entity with an @Embedded class, Objectify throws an Exception (ObjectifyTestDummy is registered):

> com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving test.ObjectifyTestDummy@2485b739: inner: test.ObjectifyInnerTest is not a supported property type.

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
@Entity
public class ObjectifyTestDummy {
    @Id
    @javax.persistence.Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Embedded
    private ObjectifyInnerTest inner;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ObjectifyInnerTest getInner() {
        return inner;
    }

    public void setInner(ObjectifyInnerTest inner) {
        this.inner = inner;
    }
}
```

And simply:

```
public class ObjectifyInnerTest {
}
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing Objectify `@Entity` with Java persistence `@Embedded` annotations. Are you using Objectify 4 or 5?https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/UpgradeVersion4ToVersion5

Comment: That's on purpose. I have a switch in my code for switching between jpa and objectify. So both versions should work. I tried with both version 4 and 5. Even if I omit the jpa annotation it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Shame on me. I switched objectify version to 5.0.5 but did not clean/package again. seems that goal appengine-devserver is not updating maven dependencies. So i was still working on Version 4.x. Why 4.x was not working I have no idea.
With 5.0.5 everything works fine.